# Javascript - Nice way to create an array from an object array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object array:

```
array = [ {x:'x1', y:'y1'}, {x:'x2', y:'y2'}, ... {x:'xn', y:'yn'} ]
```

I want to create a new array of just the `x` values:

```
[ 'x1', 'x2', ..., 'xn' ]
```

I could do this easily in a `for` loop...:

```
var newarray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     newarray.push(array[i].x);
}
```

...but I'm wondering if there's a nice one liner way to do this using jquery or even regular javascript?

Comment: The object part of your code is wrong. Your x/y objects don't have any keys. Just thought I'd point that out.

Comment: @musicfreak I think he means that his objects have two properties, x and y: {x: foo, y:bar}

Comment: @Gabe - You're right, I meant the objects have properties

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with [map](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map):

```
var newarray = jQuery.map(array, function (item) { return item.x; });
```

Answer (score 3):

ECMAScript 5 features a native `map()` method:

```
var newArray = array.map(function(value) { return value.x; });
```

In FF, this should even be faster than looping, but that's not true for all browsers (Opera); others don't even support it (IE).

Comment: If he doesn't care about a cross browser solution then in FF (which supports Javascript 1.8) he could do:

var arr = array.map(function(v) v.x);

or: 

var arr = [v.x for each (v in array)];

Comment: Unfortunately, cross browser compatibility is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Granted this is for working with a lot of data, you could use [jLinq (disclaimer: my project)](http://www.hugoware.net/tryonline) to select and query your records and then return what you want.

Again, this is really for when you're working with a lot of objects and making queries, but you might be able to get some ideas looking at the source code.